# Prolog forgetting / uninstantiating my variable?

Tags: prolog

I'm very new to Prolog, and i'm having a problem where my variable seems to be forgotten

```
test(S) :-
X = 'testing',
(S = y, write(X) );
(S = n, write(X) ).
```

Running

```
test(y)
```

Prints out the text as expected, but

```
test(n)
```

prints out

```
_L160
```

Which i assume means the variable is uninstantsiated? Why is this happening?

I know it can spit it into two predicates like:

```
test(y) :- X = 'testing', write(X).
test(n) :- X = 'testing', write(X).
```

but my actual problem is in a much larger predicate that cant be simplified like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disjunction (;) currently succeeds by either:

1. Assign 'testing' to X, y to S and write X.
   OR, if that fails, backtrace and
2. Assign n to S and write X

Add some parentheses to make it work as intended.

```
test(S):-
X = 'testing',
    (
        (S = y, write(X) )
    ; 
        (S = n, write(X) )
    ).
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the precedence of `;/2`.
If you issue a `listing(test/1)` you will get this:

```
 test(A) :-
    (   B=testing,
        A=y,
        write(B)
    ;   A=n,
        write(B)
    ).
```

which shows how the interpreter read your code.

You should parenthesize your code to get what you want:

```
test(S) :-
   X = 'testing',
   ((S = y, write(X) );
    (S = n, write(X) )).
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me re-indent the code for you:

```
test(S) :-
        (   X = 'testing', S = y, write(X)
        ;   S = n, write(X)
        ).
```

I hope it's now clearer what you actually wrote.